# Cannot change focus from dropdown to text field

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an application where I am attempting to do things a little different then they are usually meant to do.

This program will be ran in a very controlled environment, and has a specific purpose. For this part of the program, it's a form that has a text input field and a single dropdown.

Now, when "enter" is pressed on the text input field, focus is switched to the dropdown where the user will use their arrow keys to choose an option and then press "enter" again, thus submitting the form, and it should restart the form.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="card-body">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">id</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Problem</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select id="problem" class="form-control">
                <option value="none">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#id").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#problem').focus();
    }
});

$("#problem").on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#id').val('').focus();
    }
});
```

The problem is, refocusing on the text input field does not work. It appears as though the focus will switch for a half second or so, but then the focus will go back to the dropdown box.

How can I switch the focus back to the text input field and keep it there until enter is pressed again?

--edit: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwkp3m54/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the key up event will fire once the focus is back on the input if you use just key down it works.

think of it this way

keydown enter > focus dropdown > keyup > keydown enter > focus input > keyup > focus dropdown

```js
const problem = $("#problem");
const id = $("#id");

const onEnter = (e, fn) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    fn();
  }
};

id.on('keydown', e => onEnter(e, () => problem.focus()));

problem.change(e => id.val('').focus());

problem.on('keydown', e => onEnter(e, () => id.val('').focus()));
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">id</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" autofocus>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Problem</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select id="problem" class="form-control">
        <option value="none">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genious. I guess that makes sense why it would focus for a second and then switch. With your code, I have to press "enter" on the dropdown 2 times, is there a way to make it so it only has to be done a single time?

Comment: sure you have to press twice im not getting that? hmm

Comment: I'm sure. It does it in the code snippet and on my application as well. I think it's because when the focus is changed to the dropdown it opens up the options for the dropdown automatically, so then I have to press once to accept the option and again to actually register the keydown event. Another problem I can see happening is a user clicking on one of the dropdown options which would not activate the keydown event either :/

Comment: I solved both problems above by changing it to an onchange event. Thank you! I will accept your answer shortly.

Comment: I can change it to meet those requirements when I've got abit of time